# Bootstrap Checkbox table

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to use the bootstrap checkbox from this repoistory http://wenzhixin.net.cn/p/bootstrap-table/docs/examples.html

but I am unable to get the check boxes to appear I have linked to the style sheet what else would I need to have the same type of check box appear?

Answer (score 0):

In their demo page, they have loaded the following stuff realted to the table:

http://wenzhixin.net.cn/p/bootstrap-table/src/bootstrap-table.js

http://wenzhixin.net.cn/p/bootstrap-table/src/bootstrap-table.css

try add those to your resource see if it work

Comment: It is still not working. Here are all the style sheet I am using maybe one of these is affecting it?

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/3.3.0/paper/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">


  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://wenzhixin.net.cn/p/bootstrap-table/src/bootstrap-table.css"></script>
  <script src="http://wenzhixin.net.cn/p/bootstrap-table/src/bootstrap-table.js"></script>

Comment: You made a mistake that loaded the .css file as javascript, see your last line with bootstrap-table files.